# Why does food taste bland when we are sick?

Tags: flavor

Once, I had a high fever and everything I ate seemed to taste bland. Why is this so?

Comment: I'm sure this is an interesting biology/pop-sci question but it's not about cooking.

Comment: Reason for reopen vote: If you reformulate as "how to make food tasty to someone that is ill?", it becomes about cooking very much. The word "sick" also needs to go since it tends to mean the very opposite of appetite  in some regions :)

Comment: But wouldn't "how to make food tasty to someone that is ill?" be overly broad and opinion based?

Answer (score 5):

Smell.  Smell is a big portion of taste, and you likely had an upper-respiratory infection that blunted your sense of smell.